# Deploy MongoDB in k8s for development purposes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm

I'm totally newbie in k8s, but read some basic about resourses in k8s and helm trying to create simple cluster in minikube:

1. Start minikube:

```
minikube start --cpus "4" --disk-size "40000mb"
```

2. Create namespace:

```
kubectl create namespace test
```

3. Using binami helm charts for mongo with custom values.yaml:

```
replicaCount: 1

architecture: standalone

persistence:
  enabled: true
  existingClaim: "test/mongodb-data"

nameOverride: test-mongodb

service:
  nameOverride: test-mongodb
  type: NodePort
  nodePorts:
    mongodb: 30000

namespaceOverride: test

auth:
  rootUser: admin
  rootPassword: root
  usernames: ["admin"]
  passwords: ["123"]
  databases: ["test"]
```

4. Create volume.yaml for mongodb:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongodb-data
  namespace: test
  labels:
    type: local
  annotations:
    volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: standard
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/mongodb-data"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongodb-data
  namespace: test
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

5. Finally trying apply to cluster:

```
helm upgrade --install mongodb --namespace test --values ./k8s/backend/charts/mongodb/values.yaml bitnami/mongodb --wait --debug
```

As result in console see this:

```
history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release mongodb
Release "mongodb" does not exist. Installing it now.
install.go:192: [debug] Original chart version: ""  
install.go:209: [debug] CHART PATH: C:\Temp\helm\repository\mongodb-13.6.4.tgz

client.go:128: [debug] creating 5 resource(s)
wait.go:66: [debug] beginning wait for 5 resources with timeout of 5m0s
ready.go:277: [debug] Deployment is not ready: test/mongodb-test-mongodb. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready
...
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
helm.go:84: [debug] timed out waiting for the condition
```

When run see:

```
kubectl describe pods -n test mongodb-test-mongodb-7585fc9c48-rk45r

Name:           mongodb-test-mongodb-7585fc9c48-rk45r
Namespace:      test
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb
                app.kubernetes.io/instance=mongodb
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                app.kubernetes.io/name=qabat-mongodb
                helm.sh/chart=mongodb-13.6.4
                pod-template-hash=7585fc9c48
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mongodb-test-mongodb-7585fc9c48
Containers:
  mongodb:
    Image:      docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:6.0.4-debian-11-r0
    Port:       27017/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Liveness:   exec [/bitnami/scripts/ping-mongodb.sh] delay=30s timeout=10s period=20s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:  exec [/bitnami/scripts/readiness-probe.sh] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG:                    false
      MONGODB_EXTRA_USERNAMES:          admin
      MONGODB_EXTRA_DATABASES:          test
      MONGODB_EXTRA_PASSWORDS:          <set to the key 'mongodb-passwords' in secret 'mongodb-qabat-mongodb'>  Optional: false
      MONGODB_ROOT_USER:                admin
      MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD:            <set to the key 'mongodb-root-password' in secret 'mongodb-qabat-mongodb'>  Optional: false
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD:             no
      MONGODB_SYSTEM_LOG_VERBOSITY:     0
      MONGODB_DISABLE_SYSTEM_LOG:       no
      MONGODB_DISABLE_JAVASCRIPT:       no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_JOURNAL:           yes
      MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER:              27017
      MONGODB_ENABLE_IPV6:              no
      MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB:  no
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/mongodb from datadir (rw)
      /bitnami/scripts from common-scripts (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-xgpl5 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  common-scripts:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      mongodb-test-mongodb-common-scripts
    Optional:  false
  datadir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  test/mongodb-data
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-xgpl5:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  2m11s (x3 over 12m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 persistentvolumeclaim "test/mongodb-data" not found. preemption: 0/1 nodes are availab
le: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
```

What's wrong and how it fix? I try same flow with rabbitmq helm, but same result...

Comment: your pvc exist in namespace test ? you have created files but as error says check the status of pvc.

Comment: If you remove `existingClaim` and your pvc and volume resources, the bitnami chart will create the volume and claim.

Comment: @HarshManvar yes

Comment: @jordanm yes, but i have to create external pvc for future deploy

Comment: What is an external pvc and how is different than what the bitnami chart creates?

Comment: @jordanm for example i want use aws and external disk, how do that without own pvc yaml?

Comment: The bitnami charts do the same kind of pvc yaml that you specified manually. For AWS storage, you need a storage class for aws-ebs to provision an ebs PV. I am not sure what an external disk is. Do you mean external like NFS or CIFS? Docs on storageclasses are here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/.

Comment: @jordanm yes. i mean ebs, exactly. Sorry :)

Comment: I would highly recommend using EKS for k8s if you're already using AWS. It comes with that configured by default.